# DotNet Oracle ORM

Tags: .net, oracle, orm

What would be a good ORM for Oracle in .NET? I am looking for something that can auto generate the classes and mapping etc. and is free. Something closer to Linq2Sql or SubSonic.

Comment: well, it doesn't support oracle atleast not in version 3(latest)

Answer (score 4):

It seems **LLBLGen** supports Oracle. **DataObjects.Net** team works on Oracle driver also, but as far as I know it is not released yet.

Answer (score 2):

The Mindscape LightSpeed ORM has first class support for Oracle - using either the built in .NET Oracle Client or the Oracle ODP.NET Driver.

Includes full model design and schema round tripping support for Oracle from within Visual Studio to help you create classes and/or tables.

[Mindscape LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx)

Comment: Is it open source, I need something that's open source

Comment: It is not open source, but you can purchase the source if required.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a version of Hibernate which supports .NET. Hibernate for Java is highly praised, so .NET clone should be at least good :).